# Using PHP, loading coupon deals in chunks

Tags: php, loops

A site I'm working on takes table data, counts that table data and uses a standard loop to display it. Here's some of the code:

```
<?php
  $output='';   
  $count=count($deal_datas);
  $face_value="";
  $deal_price="";
  //var_dump(400*20/100);
  $save_value='';       
  $save_value_present='';   
  $category_name='';    
  $cat_ids=array();
  $deal_link='';
  $address_array=array();
  $address='';
  $website_name=''; 
  $website_data=array();

  if($count!=0) {
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
      $website_data=get_single_row("web_sites",array("id"=>$deal_datas[$i]->site_id));

      if(count($website_data)!=0) {
        $website_name=$website_data[0]->name;
      }

      $address_array=array();
      $cat_ids=explode(",",$deal_datas[$i]->sub_category_ids);

      if(count($cat_ids)!=0) {
        $where_class=array("id"=>$cat_ids[0]);
        $category_names=get_single_row("sub_category",$where_class);

        if(count($category_names)!=0) {
          $category_name=$category_names[0]->name;
        } else {
          $category_name="All";
        }
      } else {
        $category_name="All";
      }

      $face_value=str_replace("USD","",$deal_datas[$i]->deal_face_value);
      $face_value=str_replace("$","",$face_value);
      $face_value=(int)str_replace(",","",$face_value);
      $save_value_present=(int)str_replace("%","",$deal_datas[$i]->deal_save_percent);

      if($deal_datas[$i]->deal_price!="") {
        $deal_price=str_replace("USD","",$deal_datas[$i]->deal_price);
        $deal_price=(int)str_replace("$","",$deal_price);
        $save_value=$deal_price;
      } else {
        $save_value=$face_value*$save_value_present/100;
      }

      $time_zone_utc=$deal_datas[$i]->deal_oe_end_date;
      $end_date=$time_zone_utc;

      if($website_name!="kgbdeals") {
        $deal_link=base_url()."deals/iframe/".$deal_datas[$i]->slug;
      } else {
        $deal_link=$deal_datas[$i]->deal_link;
      }

      if($deal_datas[$i]->deal_address==0 or $deal_datas[$i]->deal_zip_code==0) {
        $deal_datas[$i]->deal_address="";
        $deal_datas[$i]->deal_zip_code="";
      }

      if($deal_datas[$i]->deal_zip_code!="") {
        $address_array[]=$deal_datas[$i]->deal_zip_code;
  }

      if($deal_datas[$i]->deal_address!="") {
        $address_array[]=$deal_datas[$i]->deal_address;
      }

      $address=implode(" ",$address_array);

      if($deal_datas[$i]->deal_city!="") {
        if(empty($address_array)) {
          $address.=$deal_datas[$i]->deal_city;
        } else {    
          $address.=" - ".$deal_datas[$i]->deal_city;   
        }

        //Check for valid image
        $deal_image=base_url().'uploads/deals/'.$deal_datas[$i]->slug.'.jpg';


        if(getimagesize($deal_image)) {
          $valid_image=1;
        } else {
          $valid_image=0;
        }

        if($i%2==0) {
          $output.='<div class="clsDeal_Whole_Cont clearfix">
```

Then it outputs the tabled list of data, etc.
Problem is, sometimes that data is sometimes 120 entries that are placed on the screen and the load takes ages.

What I want to do display the data 4 or 8 entries at a time. Then, as the user scrolls, add more in.

Alternatively - to load 4. Display them. Then load 4 more, display them. And so on, so that way the user actually gets to view the contents rather than waiting for the whole list (if this is simpler). Is that possible?

I'm not using jquery for this, though I know I would need to for the whole scroll down bit. So, would there be a way to rewrite the above php in order to display chunks of 4 until the final result is reached?

Comment: It's called infinite scrolling. Search for that and you'll find some libraries in jQuery etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here, beginning with how you ask the question. Be sure to include *all* the *relevant* code. You have a truncated code listing that doesn't deal with the problem at hand; how to break up a long set of data into a human readable format. You do not describe how you're getting your initial data `$deals_data`. The implementation details of how your format your output is not relevant to this question. Further, your code is a bit of the mess and doesn't follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

You should put your data selection and display functionality into single functions:

```
//returns n through z rows of data. If '0' is provided for finish, returns all rows
function getData($start=0, $finish=0 {
  $data = array();
  if ($finish == 0) {
    //get all data
  } else {
    //get limited amount of data
  }
  return $data;      
}

//returns first $limit rows of data as an html-encoded output string
function displayDeals($deal_data, $limit) {
  ...
}
```

That function should call a separate function for each of your rows:

```
//Returns a string of html-encoded data for one row
function displayRow($row_data) {
  ...
}
```

This `displayRow` function will be called `$limit` number of times by `displayDeals`. Once you get that working, it becomes much simpler to use AJAX for infinite scrolling. You simply create a php function:

```
function getMoreRows($start, $numberOfRows) {
  $data = getData($start, $start+$numberOfRows);
  $output = displayDeals($data, $numberOfRows);
  return $ouput;
}
```

This will return that output to the AJAX function that called the php code. Because it's encoded as HTML you simply replace whatever available div with that new string.

Note that JQuery will make this AJAX easy, but you will need *some* javascript in order to make this functional, or suffer a long round-trip call to a new php page each time. The latter is easy, but avoids making the user interface smooth and lazy-loaded like you want. Here is how:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
         data: {action: 'getMoreData'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      //replace your div with new data
                  }
});
```

On the server side you need a php page to handle the request:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'getMoreData' : getMoreRows($_POST['lastDataIndex'], $_POST['numberOfRowsToFetch']);break;
        // ...etc...
    }
}
```

As a minor post-script about style: you should be cautious about mixing if and if-else styles, in regards to brackets. Generally, you want you code to be tight and quickly readable, and you want to never be in doubt if code is in a block. Personally, I always use brackets with if and if-else, but you should avoid using brackets in your if statement and not in your else case at the very least. Keep an eye on human readability, or you will find that you'll be frustrated by random bugs that arise because you assume a thing is or is not in a block when it's the opposite case.

Comment: Once you get into the habit of writing things that way a lot of stuff will become easier and faster, because there will be clarity in what you're doing. Good luck!

Comment: @user1368968 By the way, I notice you have not accepted answers to any of the questions you've asked. Be sure to do this! People are more likely to answer your questions in the future, and will be thankful for the reputation you're awarding them!

Comment: Oh. I don't know how! Is it the tick to the right? I'll give that a go. I usually just click the "post was useful to you?" thing. Havent been at this long enough.

Comment: That's the one! You can give the 'accept' (green) checkmark to one answer per question you ask. You should do this! It really helps the community for a plethora of reasons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13078/discussion-between-user1368968-and-nathaniel-ford)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, ostensibly, you want to paginate the data. That's easy to do. Just have next and previous buttons on your page which are dynamically generated to link to offsets in your list (i.e. page?offset = 4, page?offset = 8). Then just load four items (offset+1, offset+2, offset+3, and offset+4) on each page.

Comment: He's not talking about pagination, it's called an infinite scroll

Comment: Which I recognize (I use it in DataTables) but he contradicted himself by saying he doesn't want to use Javascript.

Comment: Meh, I think I misunderstood what he was saying. Regardless, the concept is somewhat similar for infinite scrolling.